# Valgrind не может обнаружить опасное освобождение памяти

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind

Я изучаю valgrind и решил испробовать его на своем тестовом примере (удаление лишнего элемента в массиве). Вот пример программы (AMD64/LINUX)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    Foo(){ cout << "Creation Foo" << endl;}
    ~Foo(){ cout << "Deletion Foo" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Foo* ar = new Foo[3];
    *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(ar)-2) = 4;
    delete[] ar;
    return 0;
}
```

Но результат исполнения valgrind удивил меня:

> $ valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out -v
>
> ==17649== Memcheck, a memory error detector
>
> ==17649== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
>
> ==17649== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
>
> ==17649== Command: ./a.out -v
>
> ==17649==
>
> Creation Foo
>
> Creation Foo
>
> Creation Foo
>
> Deletion Foo
>
> Deletion Foo
>
> Deletion Foo
>
> Deletion Foo
>
> ==17649==
>
> ==17649== HEAP SUMMARY:
>
> ==17649==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==17649==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 2 frees, 73,739 bytes allocated
>
> ==17649==
>
> ==17649== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==17649==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==17649==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==17649==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==17649==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==17649==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==17649== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>
> ==17649== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
>
> ==17649==
>
> ==17649== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>
> ==17649== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Похоже на то, что valgrind не может обнаружить это опасное освобождение памяти. Насколько я понимаю это бага? или valgrind все таки умеет обнаруживать подобного рода ошибки?

UPD: Компилировал `main.cpp` командой `g++ -g main.cpp`

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48240736/5000805

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind не обнаруживает изменение "префикса" массива, так как он является валидной частью памяти. Несмотря на то, что он не должен изменяться пользовательским кодом, к нему все равно обращается код, инициализирующий массив, а valgrind не предусматривает настолько тонкий контроль доступа. Также следует заметить, что при такой операции не произошло порчи кучи и освобождение памяти завершается нормально.

Valgrid не обнаруживает вызов деструктора с невалидным объектом так как этот вызов не осущетсвляет доступ к памяти. Если добавить поле к классу, то ситуация изменится:

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    Foo(): i(0) { cout << i << "Creation Foo" << endl;}
   ~Foo(){ cout << i << "Deletion Foo" << endl;}
};
```

> Invalid read of size 4

Comment: Почему не происходит порча кучи? у меня оператор delete[] освободит большую часть памяти, чем была выделена. Я думал что ошибка должна возникнуть уже на этом этапе (момент освобождения блока)

Comment: @LmTinyToon А кусок с размером массива входит в блок, выделенный из кучи для этого массива. Так что служебная информация для освобождения самого блока видимо не затрагивается. По идее там и до этого блока видна еще какая-то запись, и после. Если еще и их повредить, тогда наверняка и освобождение сломается.

Comment: я об этом не подумал. Тогда это может обьяснить то, что работа с памятью корректна (не происходит ошибок на этапе освобождения блока). Например выделенный блок может быть выровнен (актуальный размер будет больше)

Comment: @LmTinyToon На этапе освобождения нет ошибок (в вашем варианте кода), так как в нем нет обращений к памяти. Деструктор вызывается, но обращения к /невалидной/ памяти, на которую указывает `this`, не происходит.

Comment: да, теперь стало все понятно! спасибо за отклик (и на англоязычном стеке)

Answer (score 5):

Блок памяти, выделенный при помощи `new[]` для массива объектов с нетривиальным деструктором имеет в "традиционной" реализации следующую структуру

```
[ размер блока в байтах ] [ размер массива в элементах ] [ сам массив ... ]
^                         ^                              ^
|                         |                              возвращено вам в код из `new[]`
|                         возвращено `malloc` или его аналогом
|                         и затем возвращено `operator new[]`
фактически выделено `malloc` 
или его аналогом
```

Вы исправили именно второе значение в этой веренице. Оно влияет только на вызов правильного количества деструкторов механизмом `new[]`/`delete[]`. Но оно совсем не нужно для правильного освобождения памяти механизмом `malloc`/`free` (или его аналогом). Для правильного освобождения памяти используется первое значение, которое вы оставили нетронутым. Поэтому освобождение памяти происходит нормально и не отлавливается valgrind. Так как деструкторы к памяти элементов массива не доступаются, как правильно заметил @VTT, повреждение второго поля тоже остается незамеченным valgrind.

Valgrind "знает" о внутренней организации выделенного блока памяти только, условно выражаясь, "на уровне С", т.е. он видит только первый уровень "матрешки" и знает об особой роли первого служебного поля, созданного парой `malloc`/`free`. То, что С++ внутри этой памяти создает свой уровень "матрешки", т.е. пара `new[]`/`delete[]` сохраняет еще и количество элементов массива (в случае с нетривиальным деструктором), valgrind не знает. Он считает что все, начиная с точки возвращенной условным `malloc`, является пользовательской памятью, с которой пользователь может делать что угодно. По этой причине valgrind не считает повреждение второго поля незаконным доступом, т.е. отловить его он сможет только если такое повреждение проявит себя позже, в виде наведенной ошибки.

Comment: спасибо за дополнение, я все понял. ответом зачту VTT

Answer (score 4):

Рассмотрим возможную структуру памяти, выделяемой с помощью `new-expression`
[image: new-expression]

Вы переписали хвостик, в котором содержалось количество созданных объектов. А значит в `delete-expression` будет вызвано больше деструкторов. Соответственно уже имеем UB (не наша память + вызов деструкторов для несуществующих объектов). Но в `operator delete[]` будет передан тот же адрес, что вернул `operator new[]`, и *память освободится корректно*, конечно, если до этого программа не рухнет, или не будет запущена процедура самоликвидации всего комплекса.

Comment: почему память освободится корректно? Не могу понять это утверждение, ведь разве не будет попытки удалить неинициализированную память?

Comment: Вы в курсе как работают new-expression и delete-expression и чем они отличаются от operator new и operator delete?

Comment: @Croessmah, в моем понимании, оператор delete[] освободит блок большей длины чем надо (нужно посмотреть ассемблированный код). Разве это корректное освобождение памяти? возможно я неправильно понимаю механизм работы памяти. (new expression   выделяет памяти посредством оператора new, и вызывает конструкторы (delete соответственно))

Comment: Ну вот, delete вызовет деструкторы и если не упадет, то передаст в operator delete[] тот указатель, который вернул operator new[] в new-expression. operator new и operator delete работают с сырой памятью, им без разницы что там. Считай, malloc и free (кстати, вполне вероятно, что они именно через них и реализованы).